# how to access an array of class elements react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tell me, I have a function in which I refer to an array of elements of the `mySlides` class. how to implement this correctly on react. as far as I understand there is an option through `ref`. Since I was a beginner I wanted to see an example and how to correctly implement this example. I will be grateful for the help
 index.js

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {

    showSlides() {
       let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
       for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="qwe">
                <div className="slider">
                    <div className="mySlides">
                        <p>One slides</p>
                        <img src="https://boosters.pro/api/ch/img/digital_reputation_challenge_energy-illustrations-reviews_2x.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="600" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mySlides">
                        <p>Two slides</p>
                        <img src="https://digitalageco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/slider.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="600"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mySlides">
                        <p>Three slides</p>
                        <img src="https://www.carmelon-digital.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/slider-mob-041.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="600"/>
                    </div>
                    <button>NEXT SLIDE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The official react docs will help you with this. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

**Slide.js**
You can create an archive called Slide.js inside a components folder

```
const Slide = props => {
    return (
        <div className="mySlides">
            <p>{props.name}</p>
            <img src={props.src} alt="" width="800" height="600" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Slide;
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Slide from './components/Slide';

const LoginForm = () => {
    // the array in useState is the default value for slides, and you can set its value using setSLides()
    const [slides, setSlides] = useState([
        {
            name: 'One slides',
            src: 'https://boosters.pro/api/ch/img/digital_reputation_challenge_energy-illustrations-reviews_2x.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Two slides',
            src: 'https://digitalageco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/slider.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Three slides',
            src: 'https://www.carmelon-digital.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/slider-mob-041.jpg'
        },
    ]);

    // this use effect will execute when the component did mounted
    // use it to get your slides dinamically
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     getSlides();
    // }, []);

    const getSlides = () => {
        // inside setSlides you can pass your array containing the name and src from slides
        setSlides();
    }

    return (
        <div className="qwe">
            <div className="slider">
                {slides.length > 0 && (
                    slides.map(item => (
                        <Slide name={item.name} src={item.src} />
                    ))
                )}
                <button>NEXT SLIDE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LoginForm;
```